# Why the check on the existence of the Android Kotlin notification always returns true?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

To avoid creating the notification every time, I created this method:

```
fun checkAlarm(context: Context): Boolean {

        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, NotifierReceiver::class.java)
        alarmIntent.action = ACTION_BD_NOTIFICATION

        val intFlags = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        }
        else{
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
        }

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, notificationId,
            alarmIntent,
            intFlags
        ) != null
    }
```

This is set method

```
fun setAlarm(context: Context, notificationFrequency: Long) {
        val notificationFrequencyMs = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(notificationFrequency)

        alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, NotifierReceiver::class.java)
        alarmIntent.action = ACTION_BD_NOTIFICATION

        val intFlags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        }
        else{
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        }

        val pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            notificationId,
            alarmIntent,
            intFlags
        )

        alarmManager!!.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            notificationFrequencyMs,
            pendingAlarmIntent
        )

        /* Restart if rebooted */
        val receiver = ComponentName(context, BootReceiver::class.java)
        context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }
```

In My fragments I call this:

```
if (!alarm.checkAlarm(requireContext()) && notificationIsActive) {
            alarm.setAlarm(
                requireContext(),
                30
            )
        }
```

checkAlarm is return always true, and the notification is never set, how is this possible? I call this method in the OnStart of the fragment and setAlarm it is never called before

Answer (score 0):

Using `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` alone will not check if a `PendingIntent` already exists - it will only make it immutable. You still need `FLAG_NO_CREATE`:

```kotlin
val intFlags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
} else {
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
}
```

Also ensure the `notificationId` you're using across `checkAlarm()` and `setAlarm()` is consistent.